# Hybrid App Remote DB security

Tags: security, laravel, authentication, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm attempting to create a simple Hybrid Application with native API using Cordova.
I think to use a simple REST API remote to retrieve user information.
First time users have to register into server to gain account, and then the app could manage all user's api via AJAX calls.
Now, I'll appreciate your opinions and suggestions about:

1. I thought use LARAVELL to manage routing and authentication: there's some contraindication to this approach?
2. (and principal question): I've no advanced notions about security... so someone can suggest how to manage security data and remote login?
   For example: store user password and username to localStorage, and send username + token to remote DB.
   My problem is how implement security when make remote REST call, that is how pass data for remote connection.

I hope my questions are understandable...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found complete tutorial to my answer, via JWT and access tokens.

The link is:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Very very powerful!
Hope help someone,